# I can't draw a filled rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to draw a screen with a filled in box in the center. I am using `pygame.Surface.fill()` for the box but it gives this error: **TypeError: descriptor 'fill' for 'pygame.Surface' objects doesn't apply to a 'tuple' object** Here is my code:

```
my_color = (0, 0, 0)

my_rect = (100, 100, 200, 150)

box = pygame.Surface.fill(my_color, my_rect)

surf.blit(box)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do it in two steps.  First create the surface, then fill it.  Creating a surface makes a separate image, so it takes a size not a rectangle.

```
my_color = (0, 0, 0)

my_rect = (100, 100, 200, 150)

my_size = ( 200, 150 )

box = pygame.Surface( my_size )
box.fill( my_colour )

surf.blit( box, my_rect )
```

If you just want to draw a rectangle, you can use the [drawing functions](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect), which use the base surface directly:

```
pygame.draw.rect( surf, my_color, my_rect )
```

Comment: it still gives the same error

Comment: with some further research I found that if pygame.Surface.fill takes a tuple as the first argument then it gives the error

Comment: never mind I got it to work, but thanks anyway

Comment: @SharkCoding - Ah you're right, sorry I forgot to remove the `.fill()` from the surface creation.  Please see edit.